# form not responding to query

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

I am currently working on php and html form. I want to check if duplicate user or email is there. below is my html code.

```html
<div class="container" align="center">
 <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="signup.php">
    <?php include('errors.php');?>
        <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
          <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Full name</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="First_Name" placeholder="First name" <?php echo $First_Name?> />
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-4">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Last_Name" placeholder="Last name" <?php echo $Last_Name?> />
         </div>
        </div>
        
  <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
          <label class="control-label">Username</label>
         </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Username"  <?php echo $Username?>/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
         <label class="control-label">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email"  <?php echo $Email?>/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
         <label class="control-label">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password_1" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
         <label class="control-label">Confirm Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Password_2" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info"></span>
         <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male" /> Male
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female" /> Female
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="other" /> Other
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-date"></span>
      <label class="control-label">Date of birth</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="Birthday" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"  <?php echo $Birthday?>/>
        </div>
    </div>
 <div class="input-group">
     <div class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
   <label class="control-label">Address</label>
        </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5">
       <textarea placeholder="Enter Address Here.." rows="3" name="Address" class="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
                        </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="reg_user">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

</div>
```

here is my datapost file

```html
<html>

<body>

<?php
include 'databaseconn.php';

print_r($_POST);

$First_Name = "";
$Last_Name= "";
$Username= "";
$Email= "";
$Password_1="";
$Password_2="";
$Gender= "";
$Birthday= "";
$Address= "";
$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['reg_user']))
{
$First_Name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['First_Name']);
$Last_Name= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['Last_Name']);
$Username= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['Username']);
$Email= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['Email']);
$Password_1=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['Password_1']);
$Password_2=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['Password_2']);
$Gender=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['Gender']);
$Birthday=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['Birthday']);
$Address=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['Address']);

if (empty($First_Name))
 {
  array_push($errors,"First name is required");
 }

if (empty($Last_Name))
 {
  array_push($errors,"Last name is required");
 }
if (empty($Username))
 {
  array_push($errors,"Username is required");
 }
if (empty($Email))
 {
  array_push($errors,"Email id is required");
 }
if (empty($Password_1))
 {
  array_push($errors,"Password is required");
 }
if ($Password_1 != $Password_2)
 {
  array_push($errors,"Two password do not match");
 }
if (empty($Gender))
 {
  array_push($errors,"Gender is required");
 }
if (empty($Birthday))
 {
  array_push($errors,"Birthday is required");
 }
if (empty($Address))
 {
  array_push($errors,"Address is required");
 }
}

$user_check_query= "SELECT * FROM `user_data` WHERE Username='$Username' OR Email ='$Email' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $user_check_query);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($user)
{
 if($user['Username'] === $Username)
 {
  array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
 }
 if($user['Email'] === $Email)
 {
  array_push($errors, "Email already exists");
 }
}


if (count($errors) == 0)
{
 $Password = md5($Password_1);

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `user_data` (`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`, `Gender`, `Birthday`, `Address`) VALUES ('$First_Name', '$Last_Name', '$Username', '$Email', '$Password', '$Gender', '$Birthday', '$Address')");



}

if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect)>0)
{
 echo'<p> User successfully registered </p>';
 echo'<a href="index.php"> Go BAck </a>';
 
}
else
{
 echo 'Registration not successfull';
 echo 'mysqli_error($connect)';
}


?>



</body>
</html>
```

and my database connection file is

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$databasename="smartparking";

// Create connection
$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$databasename);

// Check connection
if (!$connect) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

when I run the code and enter data, it doesn't add data to the database. it is checking for username and email. but data is not inserted for the new users.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords with a weak, high-speed hash like SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: `echo 'mysqli_error($connect)';` is probably an error.